# How to install module in Jupyter Notebooks for iPython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I am using an iPython note in Jupyter Notebooks and need to use the import [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/index.html). How can I import it such that it will become available in my jupyter notebook?

I should clarify this question applies to multiple modules (really anything you could install using pip or conda).  I am trying to determine how to install modules in a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `! pip install <package>` within the jupyter notebook.

The ! tells the notebook to run the command in bash, just make sure the pip you are using is the same interpreter the notebook is using

Answer (score 0):

Please check the installation guide for lmfit [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/index.html).

There is some problem with this package. Even after installation, import to lmfit is not possible. My advise is to ask for support [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/support.html) or check the git repository and raise an issue.

Comment: what problem do you see? using lmfit from Jupyter works for me, and most of the lmfit examples at https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/index.html have ipython/jupyter notebooks as examples.

Comment: I am not able to import this library even after installation. I also checked with different versions, still same problem.

Comment: well, if you want help with that, there are several platforms for that, including this one...  But of course, you would have to explain what you did and show the error messages you actually get.  Answering someone else's question by saying something "is not possible" when it definitely works well for many people is simply irresponsible.  It is most certainly possible to import lmfit after installation.